# Swift struct return nil issue

Tags: swift, struct, codable

I have this struct if I run this code I get nil.
I use a struct inside another struct.
Next I set first var and I put value inside another var. See code below

```
struct Main: codable{
 let name: String?
 let url: [SiteUrl]?
}

struct SiteUrl: codable{
 let url: String?
}

struct People: codable{
 let nickname: string?
 let url: [SiteUrl]
}

var test :Main?
test.url.append(“test”)

var people: People?
people?.url = test.url
print(test)//result nil
```

Comment: You never initialized test.

Comment: Read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html to help with your understanding of structs

Comment: `var people = People(...)` and then you can set its properties...

Comment: FYI, this obviously can’t really be your code, as this won’t compile. E.g., `Codable` rather than `codable`, `String` rather than `string`, etc. In the future, I might suggest you cut and paste the actual code of a working example that [reproduces](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because

`var test: Main?` is optional

You will need to first instantiate test before you can assign in.

So the answer  is

```
var test :Main?

var name: String = "name"
var url: [SiteUrl] = []

test = Main(name: name,  url )

test.url.append(“test”)

var people: People?
people?.url = test.url
print(test)//result nil
```

Alternatively, you can just do the below which is more straightforward

```
var test : Main? = Main(name: "name", [])

test.url.append(“test”)

var people: People?

people?.url = test.url

print(test)//result nil
```